# Ad-hoc network (hot spot) created in Ubuntu is not detected by android phone

Tags: 12.04, wireless, android, hot-spot

I created a hot spot via network > wireless > use as hotspot.

Other laptops successfully detected the hot-spot,could connect and use it without any problem.

But no android phone could detect it.! I tried with many android phones but none could.(I found out that even an ad-hoc created in windows is not detected by any phone)

So is there anything wrong i am doing(rather i am not doing anything actually other than clicking on the "use as hotspot" button..but still..)? or is that the network cannot be shared with phones? and if not,how can i share it with phones?

Comment: A downvote? what for?

Comment: People probably downvoted because they didn't realize the question is about Ubuntu (which it was, since you created the ad-hoc network in Ubuntu and for all you knew there was an Ubuntu-specific fix). There is no reason for someone to have assumed you weren't using Ubuntu or that your question is not Ubuntu-related ...but people make mistakes. In the long run, upvotes will cancel out downvotes (including mistaken or random downvotes).

Comment: @EliahKagan..Thanx a lot! m editing the title i guess to add ***IN UBUNTU*** ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think Android doesn't support ad-hoc networking.

Comment: Then should i select "infrastructure" instead of "adhoc"

Comment: Give it a try. It will work if your Wireless Adapter supports it. It's safe. (I haven't tried that before, though)

Comment: That probably won't work.  most wifi adapters do not support 'infrastructure' nets being hosted on them...

Answer (score 2):

Android by default doesn't allow you to connect to ad-hoc networks.
There are many patches available online that allow you to connect to ad-hoc networks, but you need to be root to apply the patch.

Answer (score -1):

Please follow this tutorial to make the adhoc connection in ubuntu , act like a wifi hotspot .

We are using hostapd for creating the hotspot .
to Install , type :   sudo apt-get install hostapd

Copy the below config to a  hostapd.conf in ur home folder .

replace the password with yours.

interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211
ssid=MyAP
hw_mode=g
channel=11
wpa=1
wpa_passphrase=MyPasswordHere
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP CCMP
wpa_ptk_rekey=600

Then , simply create an adhoc connection and issue sudo hostapd hostapd.conf in the terminal .

For detailed explanation :

http://shaer.me/blog/2012/08/how-to-enable-ad-hoc-connection-on-your-android/